# Option C: Use a ContentProvider API and a SyncAdapter Virgil's Presentation Example

Tags: android

I watched Virgi's presentation

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE (44 mins in the video Option C:)

about Developing rest applications for android and I was wondering if anyone has an example on Option C: pattern:

Option C: Use a ContentProvider API and a SyncAdapter

I have been able to find examples on Option B, but not C

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's a sample project in the Android SDK Samples called `SampleSyncAdapter`, that's a good start.

I also found this open-source [CalDAV sync adapter](https://github.com/gggard/AndroidCaldavSyncAdapater) project.

Comment: thanks, i'll keep it in mind. I don't think it uses Virgil's model, but maybe i can learn a few things from it.